# How to Change a "Home" Venue That Is Incorrectly Categorized

Tags: foursquare

this venue:

https://foursquare.com/v/111-east-85th-street/4d716ed8dadda090ffc1a5c3

Is incorrectly categorized as a home (private) instead of a residential building. I'm the mayor, how would I go about changing the type and setting the exact geo coordinates correctly?

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Report a problem" button on that page you can use to flag any problems with the venue. These flags go into a queue which gets resolved by Foursquare moderators.